# How to extract userId from curl on Jenkins build url using jq?

Tags: json, curl, jenkins, jq

I have the following output from `curl`ing Jenkins $BUILD_URL/api/json:

```
itai@Itais-MBP ~ -  $ curl -s --insecure -u itaig:password  https://ip.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/job/Company-Analytics-Prod-Deploy_New/24/api/json |
   jq -r '.actions[]'
{
  "_class": "hudson.model.CauseAction",
  "causes": [
    {
      "_class": "hudson.model.Cause$UserIdCause",
      "shortDescription": "Started by user Itai Ganot",
      "userId": "itaig",
      "userName": "Itai Ganot"
    }
  ]
}
{
  "_class": "hudson.model.CauseAction",
  "causes": [
    {
      "_class": "com.sonyericsson.rebuild.RebuildCause",
      "shortDescription": "Rebuilds build #23",
      "upstreamBuild": 23,
      "upstreamProject": "Company-Analytics-Prod-Deploy_New",
      "upstreamUrl": "view/Prod-US%20Deploy/job/Company-Analytics-Prod-Deploy_New/"
    }
  ]
}
{
  "_class": "hudson.model.ParametersAction",
  "parameters": [
    {
      "_class": "eu.markov.jenkins.plugin.mvnmeta.MavenMetadataParameterValue",
      "name": "Version"
    },
    {
      "_class": "hudson.model.StringParameterValue",
      "name": "region",
      "value": "us-east-1"
    },
    {
      "_class": "hudson.model.StringParameterValue",
      "name": "StackName",
      "value": "Company-Prd-21"
    },
    {
      "_class": "hudson.model.StringParameterValue",
      "name": "autostart",
      "value": "No"
    }
  ]
}
{}
{}
{
  "_class": "hudson.plugins.git.util.BuildData",
  "buildsByBranchName": {
    "refs/remotes/origin/master": {
      "_class": "hudson.plugins.git.util.Build",
      "buildNumber": 24,
      "buildResult": null,
      "marked": {
        "SHA1": "0e71efeac11c9909838453f4f103457ec3b04d27",
        "branch": [
          {
            "SHA1": "0e71efeac11c9909838453f4f103457ec3b04d27",
            "name": "refs/remotes/origin/master"
          }
        ]
      },
      "revision": {
        "SHA1": "0e71efeac11c9909838453f4f103457ec3b04d27",
        "branch": [
          {
            "SHA1": "0e71efeac11c9909838453f4f103457ec3b04d27",
            "name": "refs/remotes/origin/master"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "lastBuiltRevision": {
    "SHA1": "0e71efeac11c9909838453f4f103457ec3b04d27",
    "branch": [
      {
        "SHA1": "0e71efeac11c9909838453f4f103457ec3b04d27",
        "name": "refs/remotes/origin/master"
      }
    ]
  },
  "remoteUrls": [
    "git@git.assembla.com:company.ci.git"
  ],
  "scmName": ""
}
{
  "_class": "hudson.plugins.git.GitTagAction"
}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
itai@Itais-MBP ~ -  $
```

I'm trying to extract the "userId" who started the build job as the current available Jenkins plugins which are supposed to do it don't work for some reason.

This is what I tried but it gives me an error:

```
itai@Itais-MBP ~ -  $ curl -s --insecure -u itaig:password  https://ip.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/job/Company-Analytics-Prod-Deploy_New/24/api/json |
 jq -r '.actions[].causes[] | .userId'
itaig
null
jq: error (at <stdin>:0): Cannot iterate over null (null)
itai@Itais-MBP ~ -  $
```

I think it's related to the fact that there's no ".causes[]" in some of the ".actions[]" blocks, and if that's the case, is it possible to extract the "userId"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using jq, you can protect against non-existence using the post-fix "?" operator, e.g. in your case:

```
.actions[].causes[]?.userId? | select(.)
```

Answer (score 2):

Jenkins has it own api syntax which allows you to filter the api output. You can use the xml version and specify an xpath. In your case, the following url should get you the userId.

```
curl -g https://ip.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/job/Company-Analytics-Prod-Deploy_New/24/api/xml?xpath=//*/action[1]/cause/userId
```

Answer (score 0):

what about gerpping and trimming the output :

```
$ curl -s --insecure -u itaig:password  https://ip.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/job/Company-Analytics-Prod-Deploy_New/24/api/json |
   jq -r '.actions[]' | grep userId | cut -d ":" -f2 | tr -d '"," '
```

Comment: I know how to do it with cut/awk but I prefer learning how to do it with jq, thanks.

Comment: actually i prefer that too :), just think it will be appropriate to add the 'old fashion' solution also.